# Why isn't multiproccessing improving the performance of my code?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I wrote code to perform a group by and aggregation of data.  The data is constructed such that duplicates exist for the userid.  The data is grouped by the userid. The aggregated variables are just random numbers.  I wrote two versions, one without multiprocessing and the other with multiprocessing.  The multiprocessing version was slower.  Why is this so?

Without Multiprocessing

```
import time
start=time.time() 
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd


def fun_user_id(start, end, step):
    num = np.linspace(start, end,(end-start)
                      *int(1/step)+1).tolist()
    return [round(i, 0) for i in num]

def fun_rand_num():
    return list(map(lambda x: random.randint(300,800), range(1, 25000001)))

def aggregate_df(): 
    grvar=df.groupby("userid")
    dfvar=grvar.agg(varlistdic)
    dfvar=dfvar.pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.columns.map('_'.join),axis=1))
    dfvar.reset_index(inplace=True)
    return dfvar

if __name__=='__main__':
    userid=fun_user_id(1,25000001,.5)
    var1=fun_rand_num()
    var2=fun_rand_num()
    var3=fun_rand_num()
    var4=fun_rand_num()
    var5=fun_rand_num()
    var6=fun_rand_num()
    var7=fun_rand_num()
    var8=fun_rand_num()
    var9=fun_rand_num()
    var10=fun_rand_num()
    
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(userid,var1, var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10)),
                   columns =['userid','var1', 'var2','var3','var4','var5','var6', 'var7','var8','var9','var10'])
    
    varlistdic= {"var1" : ["mean","max","min"], 
                 "var2" : ["mean","max","min"],
                 "var3" : ["mean","max","min"],
                 "var4" : ["mean","max","min"],
                 "var5" : ["mean","max","min"],
                 "var6" : ["mean","max","min"], 
                 "var7" : ["mean","max","min"],
                 "var8" : ["mean","max","min"],
                 "var9" : ["mean","max","min"],
                 "var10" : ["mean","max","min"], 
                 }
    
    
    df_sum=aggregate_df()
    
    #print('End Time:',datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    end=time.time()
    print(f"Elapsed time: {end- start:.2f} seconds")
```

With Multiprocessing

```
import time
start=time.time()
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp


def fun_user_id(start, end, step):
    num = np.linspace(start, end,(end-start)
                      *int(1/step)+1).tolist()
    return [round(i, 0) for i in num]

def fun_rand_num():
    return list(map(lambda x: random.randint(300,800), range(1, 25000001)))


def aggregate_df(): 
    grvar=df2.groupby("userid")
    dfvar=grvar.agg(varlistdic)
    dfvar=dfvar.pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.columns.map('_'.join),axis=1))
    dfvar.reset_index(inplace=True)
    return dfvar
    

if __name__=='__main__':
    userid=fun_user_id(1,25000001,.5)
    var1=fun_rand_num()
    var2=fun_rand_num()
    var3=fun_rand_num()
    var4=fun_rand_num()
    var5=fun_rand_num()
    var6=fun_rand_num()
    var7=fun_rand_num()
    var8=fun_rand_num()
    var9=fun_rand_num()
    var10=fun_rand_num()


    df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(userid,var1, var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10)),
               columns =['userid','var1', 'var2','var3','var4','var5','var6', 'var7','var8','var9','var10'])

    varlistdic= {"var1" : ["mean","max","min"], 
             "var2" : ["mean","max","min"],
             "var3" : ["mean","max","min"],
             "var4" : ["mean","max","min"],
             "var5" : ["mean","max","min"],
             "var6" : ["mean","max","min"], 
             "var7" : ["mean","max","min"],
             "var8" : ["mean","max","min"],
             "var9" : ["mean","max","min"],
             "var10" : ["mean","max","min"], 
             }
   
    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        df_sum2=pool.apply(aggregate_df)
    end=time.time()
    print(f"Elapsed time: {end- start:.2f} seconds")
```

Comment: Your non-multiprocessing code is doing the processing once.  Your multiprocessing code is doing the same processing in EVERY process.  So, you have multiplied the workload.  To get any benefit, you need to SPLIT UP the processing.

Comment: Also, note that multiprocessing _by its nature_ adds overhead: you need to pass your data between processes, serializing and deserializing it. So it's _expected_ to make things slower unless you have a specific case where you're going to get more benefit by splitting work across processes than what you pay in costs.

Comment: And numpy/pandas _already_ do multithreading, so typically in a program that uses them multiprocessing is all cost and no benefit. It's not magic pixie fairy dust you can sprinkle on arbitrary programs to make them faster; it only makes things faster when they're slow in a very particular way (doing CPU-bound work that can't be effectively threaded on account of the GIL, where costs to serialize/transit/deserialize don't overwhelm the expected speedup).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things here:

- As said in other answer, the mp.Pool.apply is executed only on 1 worker. Instead, you could use mp.Pool.map (example later).

- As said in other answers, you are not parellizing the work. So, although you allocate (lets say) N workers, and if they executed the tasks given to them, you would still be giving only 1 task for each (and the same task). So, running on 10 workers is "slower or equal" than running on 1 (considering the cost of creating a process/etc, and that the time for each is the same).

- You are measuring the ENTIRE time to sample the data, create the dataframe, etc. Maybe aggregating is not the bottleneck.

Take a look at a simpler example:

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from datetime import datetime

def f(i=None):
    print(f'\t{datetime.now()}: Hi  from i: {i} pid: {os.getpid()}.\t')
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f'\t{datetime.now()}: Bye from i: {i} pid: {os.getpid()}.')

def parallelizable_task(i):
    print(f'\t{datetime.now()}: Hi  from i: {i} pid: {os.getpid()}.\t')
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f'\t{datetime.now()}: Bye from i: {i} pid: {os.getpid()}.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 2

    print('What you are doing:')
    with Pool(N) as pool:
        pool.apply(f)

    print('\nIf you had parallelizable tasks:')
    with Pool(N) as pool:
        pool.map(f, range(4))
```

Which resulted in:

```
What you are doing:
    2023-07-05 19:48:57.286638: Hi  from i: None pid: 6920.
    2023-07-05 19:48:58.298274: Bye from i: None pid: 6920.

If you had parallelizable tasks:
    2023-07-05 19:48:58.482921: Hi  from i: 0 pid: 19156.
    2023-07-05 19:48:58.492164: Hi  from i: 1 pid: 19380.
    2023-07-05 19:48:59.489039: Bye from i: 0 pid: 19156.
    2023-07-05 19:48:59.489039: Hi  from i: 2 pid: 19156.
    2023-07-05 19:48:59.497467: Bye from i: 1 pid: 19380.
    2023-07-05 19:48:59.497467: Hi  from i: 3 pid: 19380.
    2023-07-05 19:49:00.502162: Bye from i: 3 pid: 19380.
    2023-07-05 19:49:00.502162: Bye from i: 2 pid: 19156.
```

So, althout N = 2 workers were allocated, only 1 task was executed in the first case.

In the second case, 2 tasks were running simultaneously each time.

Comment: Thanks.  This is a clear illustration of how apply and map work.  In the parallel process,  Worker process 19156 is assigned to task 0.   During the execution of this task, worker process 19380 is assigned to task 1. After task 0 is completed, worker process 19156 is free and is reassigned to task 2. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the docs for `multiprocessing.Pool.apply`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply)

> `apply(func[, args[, kwds]])`
>
> Call func with arguments args and keyword arguments kwds. It blocks
> until the result is ready. Given this blocks, apply_async() is better
> suited for performing work in parallel. Additionally, func is only executed in one of the workers of the pool.

Pay specific attention to

```
func is only executed in one of the workers of the pool
```

Basically, you have a pool of workers that can execute the function, but only one is allowed to execute it at a time. So that's why you don't see a runtime improvement

Answer (score 0):

In your original code you're mostly measuring the time  required to build the dataset, because the aggregation in `pandas` runs incredibly quickly.
To give it a fair comparison I ran your code with the following modification:

```
start=time.time() 
grvar=df.groupby("userid")
dfvar=grvar.agg(varlistdic)
dfvar=dfvar.pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.columns.map('_'.join),axis=1))
dfvar.reset_index(inplace=True)
end=time.time()
print(f"Elapsed time: {end- start:.2f} seconds")
```

This runs in 0.58 seconds on my MacBook for a problem size of 1550000.

I've written up some `multiprocessing` code that splits the dataframe into chunks and processes them using 4 processes, then sticks it back together:

```
import time

import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing


def fun_user_id(start, end, step):
    num = np.linspace(start, end, (end - start) * int(1 / step) + 1).tolist()
    return [round(i, 0) for i in num]


def fun_rand_num():
    return list(map(lambda x: random.randint(300, 800), range(1, 1550000)))


def process_chunk(chunk):
    varlistdic = {
        "var1": ["mean", "max", "min"],
        "var2": ["mean", "max", "min"],
        "var3": ["mean", "max", "min"],
        "var4": ["mean", "max", "min"],
        "var5": ["mean", "max", "min"],
        "var6": ["mean", "max", "min"],
        "var7": ["mean", "max", "min"],
        "var8": ["mean", "max", "min"],
        "var9": ["mean", "max", "min"],
        "var10": ["mean", "max", "min"],
    }
    grvar = chunk.groupby("userid")
    dfvar = grvar.agg(varlistdic)
    dfvar = dfvar.pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.columns.map('_'.join), axis=1))
    return dfvar.reset_index()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    userid = fun_user_id(1, 1550000, 0.5)
    var1 = fun_rand_num()
    var2 = fun_rand_num()
    var3 = fun_rand_num()
    var4 = fun_rand_num()
    var5 = fun_rand_num()
    var6 = fun_rand_num()
    var7 = fun_rand_num()
    var8 = fun_rand_num()
    var9 = fun_rand_num()
    var10 = fun_rand_num()

    df = pd.DataFrame(
        list(zip(userid, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10)),
        columns=['userid', 'var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5', 'var6', 'var7', 'var8', 'var9', 'var10']
    )

    num_chunks = 4
    chunks = np.array_split(df, num_chunks)

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_chunks)
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    start = time.time()
    results = pool.map(process_chunk, chunks)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    dfvar = pd.concat(results)
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Elapsed time: {end - start:.2f} seconds")
    print(dfvar)
```

This code using multiprocessing on the same problem size of 1550000 took  **1.71 seconds**.

And that's where the real answer to your question is:

using multiprocessing in `pandas` like that is never likely to improve your performance. The data needs to be sent to the worker processes and that means [inter process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). This itself is often characterized by huge overhead, but in Python there is the additional penalty of having to serialize the data before sending it across a operating system pipe for IPC.

The serialization overhead means that this way of speeding up your `pandas` calculations is unlikely to help improve performance.

If your problem instances are large you're better off using [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) which is made to handle huge amounts of data and can easily scale to terrabytes of data for this kind of processing.

Comment: Thanks.  This answers my question,  I see in your code you send the data to the worker processes in the form of 4 chunks.  This as you say is characterized by huge overhead.  Each process gets one chunk and each process gets a different allocation of memory.  The data has to be organized such that it can be easily divided into the chunks and sent to the 4 processes and one grouping of records can only go to one chunk to do the aggregations.